# Android Bitmap Memory Allocation

Tags: android, bitmap

How do I check if the users Android phone has enough available memory to load a bitmap? Should I be comparing the number of bytes of the bitmap to the number of bytes available in memory? Should I be checking for the height/width and compare that to something? I am fairly new to programming and don't understand what property of the bitmap I should be comparing against the system's available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Managing BitMap Memory is already discussed in: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html